# Jquery returning invalid property value in ie6 ie7 ie8 for slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, properties

I am working on a jquery slider that  seems to work well in all browsers except for ie6 ie7 ie8. 
I am getting a invalid property value for these browsers. Strangely the slider will work if you rapidly click in the bottom square while in ie. I have remapped the $docready as I am working within wordpress.

I am working on it locally so I created a fiddle, if anybody has any solutions or ideas it would be appreciated.

[view demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webthread/kP4F2/)

Cheers Nik

Comment: In which statement, error is raising, provide us code.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on what the exact errors are, that's why I created a demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support color animation through `animate`. Removing the following statements fixes the issue for IE:

```
//headers.not(headers[num]).animate({color:hColor});

//  theHeader.animate({color:'#000'});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/kP4F2/7/

If you want to animate the color's you could include jQuery UI, which enables color animations as well.

> The jQuery UI project extends the
>   .animate() method by allowing some
>   non-numeric styles such as colors to
>   be animated. The project also includes
>   mechanisms for specifying animations
>   through CSS classes rather than
>   individual attributes.

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/kP4F2/11/

For more information what you can do with `animate`, have a look at the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). What isn't included, can most likely be done using jQuery UI.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Niklas! I was hoping it would be something as straight forward as that.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to do a little debugging in IE.

Seems like this is the cause

```
theHeader.animate({color:'#000'});
```

From what I know, you cannot animate the color property.

Comment: To catch this kind of errors there's a simple thing you can do: add some alert() displaying different messages here and there (for example at the start or end of a function), so if some of them don't appear it means that the error is in the code being called before it.